# How to initialize a PZPWSTR (wchar_t**) parameter for WinApi ldap_search_s?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, ldap

I am using `ldap_search_s` (`ldap_search_sW`) to extract AD user groups. It works when the `attrs` parameter (`PZPWSTR`, or `wchar_t**`) is `NULL`, but when I tried to specify it I got `Exception at 0x7ffc1885bd95, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0xfffffffffffffffe`.

```
wchar_t *attrs[] = {
    const_cast<wchar_t *>(L"memberOf"),
    const_cast<wchar_t *>(L"")
};
ret = ldap_search_s(pLdap, const_cast<wchar_t *>(dn.c_str()), LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, const_cast<wchar_t *>(filter.c_str()), attrs, 0, &pSearchResult);
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winldap/nf-winldap-ldap_search_sw) it needs to be "a null-terminated array of null-terminated strings indicating the attributes to return for each matching entry. Pass NULL to retrieve all available attributes."

I tried different ways using vectors, arrays, etc. and always get the same error.

[The example in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/searching-a-directory) shows only the ANSI version, but it seems to be a very similar array of pointers.

Comment: No need for the `const_casts`, string literals are automatically const.

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes, and that's why I used it. I cannot pass `const wchar_t**` to this function, only `wchar_t**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is not null-terminated. NULL and an empty string are **not** the same.

Use `NULL` (or `nullptr` in modern C++).

```
wchar_t *attrs[] = {
    const_cast<wchar_t *>(L"memberOf"),
    nullptr
};
```

Comment: And as you can see in the [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/searching-a-directory) linked to in the question, the array is terminated by `NULL`, not by `""`.

Comment: The use of const_cast is wrong. Literals are not modifiable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, but hopefully this function does not try to modify them. I cannot pass `const wchar_t**` to this function, only `wchar_t**`.